# Can I use a join in Mapviewer

Tags: oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

I've got two tables, parcels and permits.  I'd like to display permits on a map without having to copy the geometry data from parcels.  Is there a way to create a join in Mapviewer?  Do I have to create a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a view joining parcels and permits is advisable. You can use it in other situations as well (data querying etc.).

See a sample of doing so in [Joining spatial and not spatial table in oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23393/joining-spatial-and-not-spatial-table-in-oracle).